# Undo git command - git checkout --

Tags: git, git-checkout

Is there a way to undo the following git command:

```
git checkout -- .
```

I was trying to remove files that were added to the repo directory but not staged or committed. That command didn't seem to do that, instead changing some other files.

**Update:**

There's a difference between untracked filed and unstaged files. In this case, I would like to find a way to discard both untracked and unstaged files. When I ran `git checkout -- .`, I thought it would get rid of untracked files, but it only got rid of unstaged files, as far as I can tell.

Comment: in the future, if you want to remove untracked files run `git clean -dfx` and if you want to remove unstaged changes run `git reset --hard HEAD`

Comment: @kfedorov91 I wouldn't advise people to use `git reset --hard HEAD`.  It does more than just remove unstaged changes, it removes *staged* changes as well.  `git checkout -- .` is actually the right choice for discarding unstaged changes.

Answer (score 2):

#### `git checkout -- path` copies *from* index / staging-area, *to* work-tree

If the *`path`* you name is a directory, Git copies all the files it knows about (as found in the index / staging-area) into the work-tree, starting from that directory and including any sub-directories.

To make use of this answer, though, you need to know about the three active copies of every file.

#### The (up to) three copies of each file

Keep in mind that in Git, there are *up to three* versions of each file active at all times.  For instance, suppose that in your repository, you have committed files named `README.txt` and `a.ext`.  There are *three copies* of `README.txt`, and *three copies* of `a.ext`, available to you at any given time.  Two of the three copies are in a special Git-only format.

If we use the syntax that `git show` uses to access the Git-only format files, we can describe these three copies this way:

```
    HEAD             index        work-tree
---------------   -----------     ----------
HEAD:README.txt   :README.txt     README.txt
HEAD:a.ext        :a.ext          a.ext
```

If you now create a new untracked file `b.dat`, you have this:

```
    HEAD             index        work-tree
---------------   -----------     ----------
HEAD:README.txt   :README.txt     README.txt
HEAD:a.ext        :a.ext          a.ext
                                  b.dat
```

There is as yet no copy of `b.dat` in the index / staging-area.  There *are* two logically-separate copies of the other two files, *even though they are the same in both `HEAD` and the index*.  (When they are the same like this, Git shares the underlying copy automatically, so there is no extra space needed.)

#### The work-tree copies are ordinary files

Any copy of any file stored in your work-tree is just an ordinary file.  You can do anything with it that your computer will let you do.  Git does not care what you do to such files.  Git *will* tell you that the work-tree copy differs from the index copy, if you ask Git what's different.

#### `git add path` copies *from* work-tree, *to* staging-area

Suppose at this point that you modify `README.txt` using whatever editor you like, which edits the work-tree copy (it can't use or touch the index copy at all unless it knows Git rather intimately).  The work-tree copy now differs from the index copy.  The index copy is in the special Git-only format, ready to go into the next commit.

You now will need to run `git add README.txt`, to copy the updated work-tree file into the index.  When you have done that, the old version of `README.txt` is still in the `HEAD` commit, *also* in the special Git-only format, but now `HEAD:README.txt` is different from `:README.txt`, while `:README.txt` is the same as `README.txt`.

#### The `HEAD` commit copy of each file is read-only; the index copy is not

Nothing in any commit can ever be changed.  Hence the copy of `README.txt` that you committed, and the copy of `a.ext` that you committed, are safely saved away forever<sup>1</sup> in your repository.  The copy in the index / staging-area, which may or may not be the same as the one on the `HEAD` commit, *can* be overwritten at any time.  It starts out the same as the one in the `HEAD` commit,<sup>2</sup> but `git add` copies *from* the work-tree, *to* the index.

---

<sup>1</sup>If you abandon or delete a commit (typically via `git reset` or `git rebase -i`), you can cause Git to lose the frozen copy: the frozen copy only lasts as long as the commit(s) that contain it.  However, most of Git is built around the idea of *adding new commits*, without removing old ones.

<sup>2</sup>If you [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452) you can defeat the normal case of "HEAD and index match up after checkout or commit".  There is not enough room in this answer to go into these details.

---

#### `git commit` freezes all the index copies into a new commit

What `git commit` does is to take every file that is in the index at that time, in the form it has in the index at that time, and freeze it into a read-only committed copy.  This committed set of files becomes the new `HEAD` commit.  Once `git commit` has finished running and you have your prompt back, you have a new commit and your `HEAD` commit and your index match—because Git made the new commit *from* the index!

#### Untracked files

Git defines an *untracked file* very simply: it's a file that is not in the index.  That's it—that's all there is to it—but it has a strong consequence: if `b.dat` is not in the index, `git commit` won't put it in the new commit.  Moreover, `git checkout --` cannot *find* `b.dat`, because it's not in the index, so it cannot overwrite the work-tree copy.

Note that just because some file exists in *some* commit within the repository does not mean the file is tracked!  The file is tracked if and only if that file is in the index *right now*.  If you run a `git checkout` of a commit that *does* contain the file, *then*—at that time—Git will copy the file from the commit, into the index, and on into the work-tree.  *At that time* the file will be tracked.  If you then explicitly remove the file from the index, *at that time* the file will cease to be tracked.  So you must always keep in mind, or test, whether there is a copy of some particular file in your index, to know if it is tracked.

#### `git checkout commit -- path` copies *from* commit, *to* index and work-tree

Here, and with `git reset`, Git gets overly complicated, by cramming multiple different things into one command.  When you use `git checkout` *with* paths, but *without* a commit or tree specifier, Git copies from the index to the work-tree.  When you use `git checkout` with both paths *and* a commit-or-tree, Git copies into *both* the index *and* the work-tree.

#### `git reset -- path` copies *from* commit, *to* index, leaving work-tree alone

This particular form of `git reset`, used with paths, copies from a commit into the index / staging-area.  Remember, the index already has copies of all tracked files, so this just *overwrites* those copies with other copies.  By default, the commit that `git reset` uses to *get* the files is the `HEAD` commit—so this copies from the active `HEAD` copy into the index.

The work-tree copy of any file is left alone.  The fact that the file exists in the `HEAD` commit implies that the file is *probably* tracked: the only way the file could be untracked is if you checked out the commit, but then explicitly removed the index copy.  In this case, `git reset -- path` puts the file *back into* the index, so that it is once again tracked.

Note, however, that you can use `git reset commit -- path` to copy a file from some specific commit.  If that file *isn't* in the `HEAD` commit, that file may well be untracked (not in the index) before your `git reset` operation, but tracked (in the index) afterward.  This all depends on what changes you already made to the index.

#### Summary

Running `git status` does *two* comparisons:

- The first comparison is `HEAD` vs index.  Whatever is different here is *staged for commit*.

  The files that are in `HEAD` are likely also in the index (and hence all of those files are *tracked*).  If the copy that's in the index differs from the copy that is in `HEAD`, Git calls that *staged for commit*.  If the copy that's in the index is *the same* as what's in `HEAD`, the file itself is still tracked and staged—it's just that `git status` doesn't bother to *mention* it.

  The key idea here is that, even though every commit is a complete snapshot of all files, what we tend to want to know *about* a commit is: *What is different about this commit than its predecessor?*  So `git status` tells us what will be different if we take the current staging area—the proposed new commit—and actually turn it into a new commit.
- The second comparison is index vs work-tree.  Whatever is different here is *not staged for commit*.

  The files that are in the index are tracked.  For those that match what's in the work-tree, `git status` just doesn't bother to mention them.  For those that differ, `git status` mentions them, as *not staged for commit*.  For files that are not in the index at all, but *are* in the work-tree, Git whines about them being *untracked*.

  Once again, the general idea here is that we care about what's actually different in each commit, as compared to its predecessor.  If we have unstaged or even untracked files that differ from their staged copies—or lack of staged copy—we *could* use `git add` to copy them into the staging area.  If we have an work-tree `a.ext` that's exactly the same as the staged `a.ext` that's exactly the same as `HEAD:a.ext`, we probably don't care about that, so we simply don't see it at all.

  To shut Git up about untracked files that definitely *should not* be committed, you can list those untracked files (by name or glob pattern such as `*.o` or `*.pyc`) in a `.gitignore` directive.  This keeps Git from automatically adding the file in an en-masse `git add .` or `git add --all`, and keeps `git status` from whining.  Note, however, that if some file is already in the index—however it may have gotten there—listing that file's name or pattern in a `.gitignore` *has no effect*.

The primary operations that *copy* files are:

- `git add path`: copy from work-tree to index
- `git checkout -- path`: copy from index to work-tree
- `git checkout commit -- path`: copy from *`commit`* to index and work-tree
- `git reset [commit] -- path`: copy from *`commit`* (default `HEAD`) to index

The primary operations that *remove* files are:

- `git add path`: remove from index, if *`path`* is in the index but is missing from the work-tree
- `git rm --cached path`: remove from index but not work-tree
- `git rm path`: remove from index and work-tree
- `git reset [commit] -- path`: remove from index, if *`path`* is not contained in *`commit`* (default `HEAD`)

Besides these, there are some special cases you can trigger with `git commit --only paths` or `git commit --include paths`, but these are essentially equivalent to doing `git add` on those paths first.  Always keep the index in mind, and be aware that `git status` *summarizes the index's differences*, rather than listing the index's contents, so that if you have a big 30,000 file project, you see only the few *interesting* files, not all 30,000 files.